# Powershell Adjusting Column Values across multiple text files

Tags: powershell

New to Powershell and looking for some help. I have multiple xyz files that are currently displaying a z value with positive up and I need to make all the values negative (or z-positive down). So far my best attempt has been to try to cobble together what I know from other lines of code, but I'm still far from a solution.

```
$data = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\dwilson\Desktop\test" -Recurse | 
foreach ($item in $data) {$item.'Col 3' = 0 - $item.'Col 3'}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you show how your files are formatted? Several issues, first you don't need the pipe if you are using a `foreach`. Second, `Get-ChildItem` is just getting the info about the files, so you'll need to read them with something like `Get-Content` or `Import-CSV`.

Comment: Hi @BenH. The files are basically converted from CSV...

4586027.239,314214.128,55.112...


As Such. I wasn't sure how to edit multiple files at once using the Import-CSV however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat of an aside, but you're using mixed syntax here.

```
foreach ($i in $set) { ... }
```

This is the [`Foreach` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-5.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-Microsoft.PowerShell.Core).  It does not accept input from the pipeline, nor will it automatically send output down the pipeline.  See also `Get-Help about_Foreach`.

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { ... }
```

This is the [`ForEach-Object` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-5.1).  It accepts input from the pipeline and sends output down the pipeline.  Critically, this command also has a default alias of `foreach`.  See also `Get-Help ForEach-Object`.

The help for the `Foreach` statement explains how PowerShell decides what `foreach` means (emphasis mine):

> When `Foreach` appears in a command pipeline, PowerShell uses the `foreach` alias, which calls the `ForEach-Object` command. **When you use the `foreach` alias in a command pipeline, you do not include the `($<item> in $<collection>)` syntax as you do with the `Foreach` statement.** This is because the prior command in the pipeline provides this information.

Answer (score 0):

Using the looping over the files returned by `Get-ChildItem` you can import each with `Import-CSV` using the `-Header` parameter to assign the property name for each column. Then we can update the information for that property then export it. Using the `ConvertTo-CSV` cmdlet and then using `Select-Object -Skip 1` we can drop the header off the CSV before exporting it.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\dwilson\Desktop\test" -Recurse
foreach ($File in $Files) {
    $Data = Import-CSV $File -Header 'Col1','Col2','Col3'
    $newData = ForEach ($Row in $Data) {
        $Row.'Col3' = 0 - $Row.'Col3'
        $Row
    }
    $newData |
        Convertto-CSV -NoTypeInformation |
        Select-Object -Skip 1 |
        Out-File "$($File.Fullname).new)"
}
```

Comment: Hi Again @BenH. You'll have to forgive my ignorance.I copied your code into a script and gave it a run, it took some time to process before coming back with this error... 
    Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a 
    method named 'op_Subtraction'.
    At line:4 char:5
    +     $Data.'Col3' = 0 - $Data.'Col3'
    +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Subtraction:String) [], 
    RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Does this have to do with the way I'm inputting the code?

Comment: @DennisWilson Mistake on my part, you want to change each row one at a time. Can't do it all at once. Needed another loop. Answer updated

Comment: It works with that adjustment! Thank you so much. One slight problem still however, all values in the new file are now quoted. "4586027.239","314214.128","-55.112". Like so.

Comment: @DennisWilson I believe there isn't a way to stop the CSV cmdlets from quoting because it happens when there are special characters. So you can manually remove them with a regex replace. `($newData | Convertto-CSV -NoTypeInformation) -replace '"','' | Select-Object -Skip 1  | Out-File "$($File.Fullname).new)"`